# Set image dynamically in a listview by retrieving image name from a data source in android

Tags: android, image, sqlite, listview, android-listview

What is the best way to retrieve images from `drawable` folder while the name of those images are stored in a `DB` and show them in a `listView` ?

Suppose i have three pictures in `drawable` folder and their names are stored in DB as:

- pic1.jpeg
- image2.jpeg
- another_image.jpeg

I also have a method called `getAllimages()` where i retrieve image names and return them as a `Cursor` from DB:

```
public Cursor getAllImages(){
String sql = "SELECT iId as _id," + COLUMN_IMG_DESC + "," + COLUMN_IMG_NAME + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    if(cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor;
}
```

Where `COLUMN_IMG_DESC` is an `image description` and `COLUMN_IMG_NAME` is the `name of the image` stored in DB

Then i have a `CursorAdapter` where i tried to map images and their descriptions to a `listView`:

```
    ListView customListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvCustom);    
    String[] from = { DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_IMG_DESC, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_IMG_NAME};
            int[] to = {R.id.ivImg, R.id.tvTitle};
            SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_listview, cursor, from, to, 0);

cursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                ImageView imageImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImg);

                String imageValue = cursor.getString(1); //get image names
                int[] imgResourceIds = new int[cursor.getColumnCount()]; //initialize array for resource Ids
                String images[] = new String[cursor.getColumnCount()];  //initialize an array for image names   

                for(int i=0; i<cursor.getColumnCount(); i++){
                    images[i] = imageValue; //store image names to an initialized array
                    imgResourceIds[i] = getResources().getIdentifier(images[i], "drawable", packageName); //get image name
                    imageImageView.setImageResource(imgResourceIds[i]); //set image to imageView
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

            customListView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

but i got this result: How tan i solve this?
[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was that i was assigning my *Adapter Layout Parameter* wrong. Instead of **ListView_Row** i was pointing to **ListView** itself

So:

```
 SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_listview, cursor, from, to, 0);
```

Would be:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_listview_row, cursor, from, to, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get an image from the drawable folder with a dynamic name this way:

```
resources.getIdentifier(String imageName, String folder, String package);
```

This returns an integer the same way you would type

```
R.drawable.imageName;
```

An example of how to use it:

```
Bitmap bitmap[] = new Bitmap[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    bitmap[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
        resources, 
        resources.getIdentifier("pic" +i, "drawable", "com.example.com")));
```

This gets images from "pic0.png", "pic1.png" ... until "pic4.png", of course you can customize it the way you want

Comment: Thanks for helping @TomTsagk but what if the names of the images are different from each other like the example i edited now: 
1.pic.jpeg, 2.image.jpeg, 3.another_image.jpeg...
does this mean that i have to rename all my images in db?

Comment: @hrskrs if you didn't notice I used "pic" +i  that means if you enter that inside a for loop you can get "pic0.png", "pic1.png"... "picX.png" and store them inside an array or anything (the ".png" part is ignored when dealing with images inside drawable folder) :)

Comment: yeah i noticed that but the question i am asking is that what if the picture names are different from each other?? not like pic1.jpeg, pic2.jpeg but as pic1.jpeg, image_2.jpeg, another_image.jpeg?

Comment: @hrskrs you can save the names in a String array and on the imageName part type stringArray[i] or something like that, I'm not sure how you have the names saved

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] resID = new int[2]
String[] mDrawableName=new String[2];
mDrawableName[0] = "pic1";
mDrawableName[1] = "image";
mDrawableName[2] = "another_image";

for(i=0:i<=2:i++)
int resID[i] = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName[i] , "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Usage

```
image.setImageResource(resID[0]);
```

Comment: @TomTsagk I tried smth like this (edited the question) -> updated cursorAdapter and added an image of print screen. That is the result i am getting. Where is my mistake?