# NullPointerException while trying to bind at SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android

I have asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368871/set-image-dynamically-in-a-listview-by-retrieving-image-name-from-a-data-source/25451750#25451750) before where i found my mistake. However now i am facing with another problem. I have checked all the similar errors asked on **StackOverflow** but without success.Any help is appriciated.

The idea here is that i am getting image names from DB so depending on those names images from `Drawable` folder will be shown in a `listView` together with a description but im getting an error of `NullPointException` at `setViewValue`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
private void populateListView() {
    ListView customListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvCustom);

    Cursor cursor = DBhelper.getAllimages();

    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] from = { DBhelper.COLUMN_PIC_URL, DBhelper.COLUMN_PIC_DESC};
    int[] to = {R.id.ivImg, R.id.tvTitle};
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_listview_row, cursor, from, to, 0);

    cursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            ImageView imageImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImg);
            String[] imgNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            int[] imgResourceIds = new int[cursor.getCount()]; 
            for(int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++){
                imgNames[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_PIC_URL));
                imgResourceIds[i] = getResources().getIdentifier(imgNames[i], "drawable", getPackageName());
                imageImageView.setImageResource(imgResourceIds[i]);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            return true;
        }
    });

    customListView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);

}
```

Here is the *Error* from `LogCat`:

[image]

I have tried to log the output of `imgNames[i]` where it returns the url pic from the DB correctly and `imgResourceIds[i]` where it return the image resource id correctly also(it does not return NULL but something like: 295731). But it stops at `imageImageView.setImageResource(imgResourceIds[i]);`

To see from where that `NullPointerException` is coming, i commented out `imageImageView.setImageResource(imgResourceIds[i]);`. This time **imageNames(those with a TAG) and imgResourceIds(those system printed out)** came correctly but doubled, when i removed `cursor.MoveToNext()` last row were doubled. Here is the screen shot of that:
[image]

I have tried all the suggestions on stack about gettin a NullException but without success. Any idea where i am doing mistake?

Comment: Which line within setViewValue() is the NullPointer in question?

Comment: @JaySnayder I logged all the parameters and no one returns null but the application breaks at `imageImageView.setImageResource(imgResourceIds[i]);`

Comment: Well of course one of them returns null.  That's why the error is being thrown as a NullPointer.  You just have to figure out if it's an imageName not coming back right causing it, or the getIdentifier that's the problem, or something else entirely with the setup that is causing a null value to be returned for setImageResource()

Comment: @JaySnayder `imageName` is coming well(it was stored with .jpg extension on DB but i removed it) 
`imgResourceIds` also not null...but as it is inside the loop only first element of array is shown (in LogCat) and the loop is broken after first parameter, right after it gets the `imgResourceIds`. It looks like the problem is when i try to `setImageResource`

Comment: @JaySnayder i edited the question. Can you check it, maybe you catch the point i am missing?

Comment: Which line is line 50? i.e. which line is throwing the NPE?

Comment: @user3249477 its the line where `imageImageView.setImageResource(imgResourceIds[i]);` is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys the problem was at `return` statement. One thing that i was ignoring was that `setViewValue` requires a `validation` about `return` statement.

Before starting any action in `setViewValue` initialise a `boolean` value to false`and if the action is successful assign the value to`true` and return that value:

```
boolean binded = false;

if(view instanceof ImageView){
//your actions
binded = true;
}

return binded;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear where the `ImageView` is actually located. But judging from this line

```
int[] to = {R.id.ivImg, R.id.tvTitle};
```

It looks like it's a part of each `ListView`s item. So you should be finding the view inside of the item.

Try this line and see how it goes:

```
ImageView imageImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImg);
```

Also, I find it weird that you are looping `setImageResource` on the `ImageView`.

This is what your ViewBinder should look like:

```
cursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        ImageView imageImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImg);
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBhelper.COLUMN_PIC_URL));
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable",
                getPackageName());
        imageImageView.setImageResource(resourceId);

        return true;
    }
});
```

Then again I don't understand why you are using a ViewBinder when the CursorAdapter can handle setting an ImageView by itself.

Comment: Tried that but same NPE at the same line.
`R.id.ivImg` its an `ImageView` defined in a `custom_listview_row` layout (which is a layout for a row of a `ListView`)

I am looping `setImageResource` to set every image from the array. Is there any other way to set multiple image resource IDs?

Comment: @hrskrs but you are setting them all to the same ImageView, I don't see what's the point in that.

Comment: how can i set different ones? I didnt get your point. ImageView is an item of a ListView. What i am trying to achieve is that i put all images from DB to a ListView

Comment: @hrskrs updated the answer, I doubt it will work though. However hopefully you can at least get a glimpse on how ViewBinder should work.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe you did not initialize the ImageView in ivImg in layout file. Check if you have defined ImageView R.id.ivImg in custom_listview_row

Comment: Yeah i double checked and it is defined